# Access phpmyadmin database from a website via a link?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Is there anyway of accessing phpMyAdmin via a link on a website. What i mean is, I got an admin panel that contains links to other pages on my website and I want to add a link that will gain access directly to the database. Upon clicking this link, it would ask for a username and password. Login pages i know how to do.

I have searched for a while and could not find anything like this. Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you looking for more than `<a href="http://link.to/phpmyadmin">PHPMyAdmin</a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is way to access with php files

Adminer (formerly phpMinAdmin) is a full-featured database management tool written in PHP

you can download from [`site link`](http://www.adminer.org/)

and install in your database to use.

let me know if i can help you more

Comment: ok i will try this and get back to you. Thanks alot, this might help alot

Comment: OK, I have visited the link you have provided and it looks like something i need but does this get implemented into phpmyadmin?

Comment: The problem is my website is using XAMPP and phpmyadmin. If I have to swap over to Adminer, then do I have to redo config files?

Comment: there is no any relation with config files with adminer. it is independent.

Comment: So the adminer.php that i downloaded. Do i have to point the link to this php file on my admin panel?

Comment: it is separate file just upload in your directory where your source code is there for examlpe www.yourdomain.com/adminer.php files

Comment: OK, it works with WAMPP by simply putting the adminer.php file in the WAMP/WWW folder. and this can be accessed by typing localhost/adminer in the URL.  Sadly somehow it did not work with XAMPP.

Comment: you can also use it with xampp to put in htdocs/adminer.php so you can access like http://localhost/adminer.php.  
BTW glad to help you @munue

Comment: hey thanks, i have managed to make it work with XAMPP as well. I have noticed that there is a useful plugin called DatabaseHide for Adminer. How do you use this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible just download and copy, cofigure phpmyadmin to a subfolder on your htdocs folder of your site.

Comment: when you say configure phpadmin to a subfolder, do you mean export the database to that subfolder?

Comment: @munue  You don't have to do anything to database.

Just download and copy the files to sub folder and edit config.inc.php
Document for this: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install